# Grails: Spring Security Core Custom authentication getUserByUserName return null object

Tags: grails, spring-security, authorization

I'm writing a custom authorization service with Grails 2.4.4 and the Spring Security Core plugin and having trouble creating the `user` object below.  It's always null, but the userName and password passed into the service are valid and correct strings. (Eventually, I will replace the authentication with a custom service, but I want need to prove I can call the methods to complete that task.)

Does anybody know what I'm doing wrong?

The settings in `Config.groovy` allow me to correctly invoke this provider.

```
grails.plugin.springsecurity.providerNames = ['CustomLDAPAuthProvider','daoAuthenticationProvider']
```

The necessary files in resources.groovy are also set correctly.

```
beans = {   
    CustomLDAPAuthProvider(com.mathworks.spikeLDAP.CustomLDAPAuthService)
}
```

Here is the service code that doesn't work...

```
package com.mathworks.spikeLDAP

import grails.gsp.PageRenderer;
import grails.transaction.Transactional

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationProvider
import org.springframework.security.authentication.BadCredentialsException
import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication
import org.springframework.security.core.AuthenticationException
import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.SimpleGrantedAuthority
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User

@Transactional
class CustomLDAPAuthService implements AuthenticationProvider {

    def springSecurityService       
    PageRenderer groovyPageRenderer    

    @Override
    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication arg0)
            throws AuthenticationException {

        if (arg0) {
            println ("arg0 is not null")
        } else {
            println ("arg0 is null")
        }

        def userName = (arg0 as UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken).getPrincipal()
        println ("username="+userName)
        def password = (arg0 as UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken).getCredentials()
        println ("password="+password)
        User user = springSecurityService.getUserByUserName(userName)

        def providedPassword = springSecurityService.encodePassword(password, user)
        def realPassword = springSecurityService.getUserPassword(user)

        if(!providedPassword.equals(realPassword)){
            throw new BadCredentialsException("Bad login credentials!")
        }

        def authorities = springSecurityService.getUserAuthorities(user)
        return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(user, arg0.credentials, authorities)

    }

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> arg0) {

        return true;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are defining a new bean which is dependent on another bean, looks like it should be done like following code mentioned in the doc

```
beans = {
    myBean(MyBeanImpl) {
        someProperty = 42
        otherProperty = "blue"
        bookService = ref("bookService")
    }
}
```

http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/guide/spring.html#theUnderpinningsOfGrails